# PADS for land pattern coilcraft

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, footprint, pad, schematic

[image]

How can you even make a footprint/ land pattern with this info. Is that land pattern the pads? Is that a wire going into the model, meaning my pad just needs to touch either side of the component? Seems very weird to not just include a pad pattern for the land pattern.

Comment: it is unclear what difficulty you are facing ... the document includes a land pattern ... *land* and *pad* are synonymous here

Comment: The two grey C shaped blocks in the land pattern you show are the two terminals of the coil. You just need to design a footprint that has two pads of the shape shown.

Comment: ahhh, I did not know that you could make different shapes with pads, as I am new to fusion 360. I think thats not possible in fusion 360, right? That is the first thing I looked into.

Comment: When you say "PADS" are you referring to the layout tool made by MentorGraphics/Siemens or are you just shouting the word "pads"?

Comment: If you don't know what pads are, you're chiming into the wrong forum.  Questions tagged [pad]
For questions about PCB pads, which are exposed regions of metal that component leads are soldered to. Use in conjunction with "pcb" and/or related "pcb-" tags (e.g. "pcb-fabrication"), as applicable.@ThePhoton

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Found how to do it in fusion 360.

Comment: Text is better than an image. An image is not text searchable.

Answer (score 0):

A land pattern can be referenced to generate a footprint as they are roughly the same (say for a PCB design).

The measurements are given so you can generate a footprint easily with what is provided. If you need to make minor adjustments to the pads, say you want to be able to hand-solder the component on, you can widen the outer edges of the pads.

You can also give a thou or two (0.001 in) of extra pad space (if there is room for it) so solder paste can reflow nicely.

This looks like a standard footprint, so there may already be one designed for F360. It may also specify the footprint type in the datasheet.

Just make sure to keep the inside distances consistent to prevent any issues.

Comment: Yes, this doesnt seem to have a footprint associated with it, nothing on mouser, snapeda,  or the manufacturers website. The footprint is listed as " 4.4x4.4mm" and "Custom" on snapeda, for the whole line of inductors. The data sheet is here. I have followed the manufacturer for everythin else on this pcb design, but no luck on this last footprint, so I am having to make it myself now. https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/597/lps4414-270736.pdf